# Syncfusion MAUI DataGrid and VerticalStackLayout

Tags: maui, syncfusion, sfdatagrid

I would like to add label above Syncfusion Datagrid but the label is hidden when I run the app in the following page.

See the following [repos](https://github.com/JeanMarcFlamand/MauiSyncFusionExamples) for complete app.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DataGrid.Views.OrderInfoRepositoryView"
             xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.DataGrid;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.DataGrid"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGrid"
             Title="Order Info Repository View">


    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:OrderInfoRepositoryViewModel x:Name="viewModel" />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="20"
                             Spacing="10">

            <Label Text="OrderInfo"
                   Margin="10,10,10,10"
                   TextColor="White"
                   BackgroundColor="Red"/>

            <syncfusion:SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding OrderInfoCollection}">
            </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
        
        </VerticalStackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Did try the following but same result.

```
    <Label Text="OrderInfo"
           Margin="10,10,10,10"
           TextColor="White"
           BackgroundColor="Red"/>

    <syncfusion:SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding OrderInfoCollection}">
    </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>

</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Here Android screenshot
[image]

Added LineHeight and fontSize. No change
[image]

Tested with HeightRequest. No change.
[image]

Comment: please post a screenshot illustrating the problem

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: weird.  Try specificity a height for the Label?

Comment: Code updated. No change

Comment: Use HeightRequest to set a height

Comment: Code updated. No change.

Comment: Did post the question on Syncfusion forum https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/179675/syncfusion-maui-datagrid-and-verticalstacklayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have set the Content for the ContentPage as DataGrid in OrderInfoRepositoryView.xaml.cs file. Please refer to the below file,

https://github.com/JeanMarcFlamand/MauiSyncFusionExamples/blob/master/DataGrid/Views/OrderInfoRepositoryView.xaml.cs#L12

You are adding the DataGrid as the content of the page in code behind i.e., OrderInfoRepositoryView constructor. That’s why the DataGrid alone is displaying without Label. We request that you remove the codes inside the OrderInfoRepositoryView constructor to overcome the issue.